# Java - Shiro - ehcache config

Tags: java, spring, ehcache, shiro

I am using `Shiro`(v1.2.3) in a java web project using `Spring` (v4.1.4).

I enabled `Ehcache` for shiro, to help store shiro session.

---

**My question is:**

Do I need to define a `<cache>` entity for shiro session in ehcache.xml config file, or shiro will manage that automatically?

In one word, do I need to put following config segment into `ehcache-shiro.xml`:

```
<cache name="shiro-activeSessionCache" maxElementsInMemory="10000" overflowToDisk="true" eternal="true"
    timeToLiveSeconds="0" timeToIdleSeconds="0" diskPersistent="true" diskExpiryThreadIntervalSeconds="600" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No you don't need to if the default settings are fine for you. An [ehcache.xml](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.shiro/shiro-ehcache/1.2.3/org/apache/shiro/cache/ehcache/ehcache.xml?av=f) file is part of the shiro-ehcache module and would be used by default. The setting you are quoting is identical to the one defined in this file. As the [Shiro doc about session management](http://shiro.apache.org/session-management.html#SessionManagement-EHCacheSessionCacheConfiguration) mentions:

> By default, the EhCacheManager uses a Shiro-specific ehcache.xml file
>   that sets up the Session cache region and the necessary settings to
>   ensure Sessions are stored and retrieved properly.
>
> However, if you wish to change the cache settings, or configure your
>   own ehcache.xml or EHCache net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager instance, you
>   will need to configure the cache region to ensure that Sessions are
>   handled correctly.
>
> If you look at the default ehcache.xml file, you will see the
>   following shiro-activeSessionCache cache configuration:

```
<cache name="shiro-activeSessionCache"
        maxElementsInMemory="10000"
        overflowToDisk="true"
        eternal="true"
        timeToLiveSeconds="0"
        timeToIdleSeconds="0"
        diskPersistent="true"
        diskExpiryThreadIntervalSeconds="600"/>
```

> If you wish to use your own ehcache.xml file, ensure that you have defined a similar cache
>   entry for Shiro's needs

Comment: I saw a cache called `org.apache.shiro.realm.text.PropertiesRealm-0-accounts` in the default config file, can you help explain what that do, thx.

Comment: hey, take a look at this explanation at the mailing list, but in general you shouldn't worry as this is part of the internal implementation of the lib: http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/shiro-user/201208.mbox/%3CCAAtvD4Xbo=rJfJ1NueAmOSuSMav01JccvJ34X0V-XVgURP3pLg@mail.gmail.com%3E